# How do I handle the server hostname with multiple web sub-domains and email?

Tags: email, web-server, sendmail, hostname

A while back, I set up a server using nginx for a web site, example1.com, along with email using sendmail and all went well. Recently, I set up a second web site, example2.com, along with email in the same manner. However, I had forgotten that the original hostname for this server was set to "example1.com". If you were to look at the actual text of the emails for example2.com, they show the Return-Path as coming from "john@example1.com" instead of example2.com.

The receiver of the email has no indication of this but I don't want them to be able to know that.

So I don't know if this is a change to be made to my hostname or something I need to change in sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something you'll need to change in sendmail. You can have sendmail provide mail for multiple domains.

You'll want to look at the sections of the sendmail documentation relating to virtual domains, masquerading and relaying.

Comment: I have sendmail working for both domains. And users are getting mail from example1.com and example2.com. It's just that the return path in the actual text (forgot what it's called "on the wire") says it's from example1.com. Or are you saying it's still a sendmail setting?

Comment: Yes, it is a sendmail setting!